# calling jmeter remotely doesnt terminate the execution thread

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

When I am calling jmeter remotely through jmeter-maven plugin called by Team City, the Jmeter doesn't terminate the test execution. It starts the .jmx execution, but never exits.

It seems to be related to https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/37 , but although similar issues are reported as not reproducible (two years ago), I can still see it on  jmeter 2.11.

Any suggestions of how to address it?

Comment: Could be this bug: https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/108